# How to resolve "OSError: JVM cannot be restarted" error?

Tags: python, jpype

I'm having the below piece of code in Python trying to start a Java virtual machine through Jpype.

```
            if not jpype.isJVMStarted():
                jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath())
            
            if jpype.isJVMStarted():
                print("JVM Running")
                
            # Example: Call a Java method
            java_list = jpype.JClass('java.util.ArrayList')()
            java_list.add('Hello')
            java_list.add('World')
            
            # Access the Java list from Python
            for item in java_list:
                print(item)
            
            # Shut down the JVM
            if jpype.isJVMStarted():
                jpype.shutdownJVM()
```

This produces the following logs:

```
JVM Running
Hello
World
```

Then errors out like below:

```
File "C:\ProgramData\FICO\XpressInsight\Worker\work\executions\832925fb-7480-48ef-90c3-8af57a6c9416\model\xprm_3d00\python_source\application.py", line 1439, in investigate_metaphors
jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath())
File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\jpype\_core.py", line 169, in startJVM
raise OSError('JVM cannot be restarted')
OSError: JVM cannot be restarted
```

The logs tell me that JVM already started. Why am I still getting this error on line jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath())?